# Get the biggest value from array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array where i need to get the biggest value but the biggest key

```
Array = [
   0 = 2,
   1 = 2, 
   2 = 1,
   3 = 1,
],
```

the biggest value from array above are 2, but there's `2` keys where it has values of `2` which is `0` and `1`. somehow i need to get the key of array where it's biggest one so the key are 1. and i just can't reorder the value since it'll mess up the key value because i'm gonna need the key

Comment: Would be efficient to say what have you tried already?

Comment: get the maximum value, get the keys behind it and sort it in reverse, then you get the highest key with the highest value, you can use a `max`, `array_keys`, and `arsort`

Comment: Does this code even compile? Shouldn't this be `[0 => 2, 1 => 2, …]`?

Comment: @Kevin if i'm not mistaken, i've tried to use ```sort``` method then it completely mess the key arrange men. e.g ```[0 => 1, 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 2]``` which i can't do that since i really need the key

Comment: @knittl i post the output of an array

Comment: @MartinChristopher `arsort` maintains key indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this help you , first will get highest value with max($array) then will get max key

```
$array = array('2','2','1','1');

$highest_num = max($array);


$highest_key = max(array_keys($array,$highest_num));

print_r($highest_key);
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to first filter the associative array, retaining only entries whose values are coincident with the highest value.  Then, take the max value of `array_keys()` of that subarray to find the highest key.

```
$array = Array
(
    0 => 2,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1
);
$array_max = array_filter($array, function($elem) USE ($array) {
    return $elem == max($array);
});

echo max(array_keys($array_max));
```

Comment: @danish Sorry, I fixed it (I am on a cell phone).

Comment: also there's no need for `array_values` in `max(array_values($array));` `max($array)` is all good. isn't ?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a loop that progresses through the array, along with two variables that you update appropriately as needed:

- `maxValue`: The largest value seen so far
- `maxKey`: The key for the largest value seen so far

During the loop, check the current element's key and value against these. If the value matches `maxValue` but the key is greater, update `maxKey`. If the value is greater than `maxValue`, change BOTH `maxKey` and `maxValue` to match the current element's key and value.